# "Dernier", "prochain", etc. with numbers

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

The adjective *dernier* can be placed in front or after a noun it modifies, but gives different meanings in the two cases:

> J'ai eu un accident la semaine **dernière**.
>
> C'est la **dernière** semaine de l'année !

What if there is a number that modifies *dernier*? Is it always placed in front of the noun?

> (1) J'étais très occupé les **deux** **dernières** semaines.
>
> (2) Cet événement aura lieu pendant les **deux dernières** semaines de l'année !

Is it the same with *prochain*, *suivant*, and *premier*?

> (3) Je serai très occupé les **deux** **prochaines** semaines.
>
> (4) J'ai eu un bon moment aux vacances. Mais les **deux suivantes** semaines, j'étais très occupé.
>
> (5) Cet événement aura lieu pendant les **deux premières** semaines de l'année !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1), (2), (3) and (5) are perfectly correct.
For the (4), it would rather be "les deux semaines suivantes"

Now, if I had to give you a "rule" and not just answer because "it sound better like that", it would more difficult...

EDIT:

I just found this link, which seems quite acurate to me, but not perfectly written, let me know if you need help to understand

http://activitesfle.over-blog.com/2015/04/prochain-dernier-place-de-l-adjectif-et-changement-de-sens.html

Answer (score 0):

To put it as simple as I can, "dernier" is exactly the same as "last".

> I had an accident last week.
>   It is the last week of the year.

You can usually change the order too, but it might sometimes not sound right.

> The (last 2 / 2 last) weeks have been hard.
>   Ces (2 dernières / dernières 2) semaines ont ete difficiles